# How would I prove the following using the AGM inequality?

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> **Question 17.** Let $x,y\in\mathbb R$, $x,y\geq0$. Prove that $$(\sqrt x+\sqrt y)^2\geq2\sqrt{2(x+y)\sqrt{xy}}.$$

I believe I have to use AGM multiple times, but I am not exactly sure how

Comment: AM-GM on $x+y$ and $2\sqrt{xy}$

Comment: thank you, How would I get to the 2(x+y) part though?

Comment: I’ve posted it as an answer, sorry if there are any typos, I am on a phone.

Answer (score 4):

AM-GM for 2 numbers is $\frac{a+b}{2}\geq \sqrt{ab}$. Let $a=x+y$ and $b=2\sqrt{xy}$:

$$\frac{x+y+2\sqrt{xy}}{2}\geq \sqrt{2(x+y)\sqrt{xy}}$$

Multiply both sides by 2 and factor the left hand side to get:

$$x+y+2\sqrt{xy}\geq 2\sqrt{2(x+y)\sqrt{xy}}$$

$$(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y})^2\geq 2\sqrt{2(x+y)\sqrt{xy}}$$

Comment: oh wow this is an extremely neat proof! Thank you so much for your help:) I was thinking more of items of proving separate parts of it and then multiplying it up or something.